# How to take correct word from filtering(list view) using with pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

Here in my sample program, i want to take the item from another widget using with list view.In my autosuggestion i have list of items, those are total_list1 =["renewal form","auto renewal form","store products","store programs"].In that i want to choose "renewal form" means it automatically tacking the ""auto renewal form" item.I don't have any idea about this.Can any one please help me how to solve this program.Thank you in advance.

Given below is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        Box=QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.le=QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.btn=QtGui.QPushButton("s")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.items_list)
        Box.addWidget(self.le)
        Box.addWidget(self.btn)
    def items_list(self):
        self.w=QtGui.QWidget()
        vbox1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.w)
        hbox1=QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.le_search = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        se_btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("Search")
        se_btn1.clicked.connect(self.filterClicked1)
        hbox1.addWidget(self.le_search)
        hbox1.addWidget(se_btn1)
        vbox1.addLayout(hbox1)
        total_list1 =["renewal form","auto renewal form","store products","store programs"]
        self.list1 = QtGui.QListView()
        self.model1 = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.list1)
        for code in total_list1:
            item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(code)
            self.model1.appendRow(item1)
        self.list1.setModel(self.model1)
        vbox1.addWidget(self.list1)
        self.w.show()
    def filterClicked1(self):
        self.w.close()
        filter_text = str(self.le_search.text()).lower()
        for row in range(self.model1.rowCount()):
            if filter_text in str(self.model1.item(row).text()).lower():
                self.list1.setRowHidden(row, False)
                print self.model1.item(row).text(), "wordd"
                self.le.setText(self.model1.item(row).text())
                self.le.setCursorPosition(0)
            else:
                self.list1.setRowHidden(row, True)
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am selecting here "renewal form"

[image]

but i am getting the auto renewal form

[image]

Comment: sir i updated my code with images please check once

Comment: i have problem with renewal form sir when i wrote renewal i want to get renewal form

Comment: sir break  is worked exactly .Thank you